# How can I select all rows that come right NEXT after rows which meet a specific criterion?

Tags: r

Is there a possibility that R can extract the NEXT row (choosen row+1) after a row that meets specified criteria? For instance I select specific rows in my data

```
df1[df1$criterion == "example", ]
```

but I am not interested in these rows but every first row that follows one of those which fullfil the criterion...

Comment: Maybe `df1[which(df1$criterion == "example") + 1, ]`?

Comment: Look at `?which`

Comment: Very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
indices <- which(df1$criterion == "example")[- nrow(df1)] + 1
df1[indices, ]
```

Basically, you use which to convert you `TRUE`/`FALSE` mask into indices. The part `[- nrow(df)]` tackles the case where the last element of your mask is `TRUE` by removing it (whatever its value).

Answer (score 0):

```
df[c(F,df$criterion == "example")]
```

This just offsets the masking flags by appending a FALSE at the start.

Comment: This does not work because there are more elements in `c(F,df$criterion == "example")` than in `df`. You should do: `c(F,(df$criterion == "example")[- nrow(df)])`

Comment: You're right. It would help if OP said what behavior should occur if the last entry has criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Another basic solution:

```
df1$cummeet <- cumsum(df1$criterion == "example")
df1[df1$cummeet > 0]
```

By using cumulative sum, you can see all rows after that specific row.